# Key of highest occurring value in JavaScript map?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

Given a JavaScript **map** of **(key, value)** pairs.
Find the 'key' of highest frequency 'value' ( say **x** ).
Given that the frequency of the value (**x**) in map must be greater than 50% of size of map.

```
var m = new Map;
m.set('0', null);
m.set('1', 'a');
m.set('2', 'a');
m.set('3', 'a');
m.set('4', 'b');
m.set('5', 'a');
m.set('6', null);
```

Here the answer can be **1, or 2, or 3, or 5**  as **a** has frequency of **4** which is greater than 50 % of size of map **7**.

---

```
var m = new Map;
m.set('0', null);
m.set('1', 'a');
m.set('2', 'a');
m.set('3', 'a');
m.set('4', 'b');
m.set('6', null);
```

Here the answer is **-1**  as **a** has frequency of **3** which is equal to 50 % of size of map **6**.

---

[**NOTE**] : If multiple answers exist e.g. 1, or 2, or 3, or 5,  **randomly** select one of them.

---

My Algorithm :
Create a frequency map of values of original map say freqMap.
Find the key (say x) having largest value in freqMap.
Check weather x has value greater than 50 % of original map size.
Find all the keys having value x in the original map.
Randomly select any one of them by randomizing.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: FYI, I amn't. I am working around 51% rule in PoW algorithm and I am new to JS.

Comment: The expectations are the same: you should try to solve it yourself, and post what you tried. Then we'll help you understand what you did wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: I have added my algorithm, but I was facing syntactic errors while implementing  it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var m = new Map;
m.set('0', null);
m.set('1', 'a');
m.set('2', 'a');
m.set('3', 'a');
m.set('4', 'b');
m.set('6', null);

const getHighestOccuringKey = (map) => {
//Create a new object with frequency/count along with the keys
  const obj = {}
  for (let [key, value] of map.entries()) {
    if(obj[value]) {
    //if the value is already present, push the new key to the keys and increment the count
      obj[value] = {keys: [...obj[value].keys, key], count: obj[value]?.count + 1}
    } else {
    //else create a new object with value as key and add keys array along with the count
      obj[value] = {keys: [key], count: 1}
    }
  }

//Sort based on the count
  const sortedArr = Object.values(obj).sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);
  
  //Check if the freq/count is more than 50%
  //If so, return a random key
  if(sortedArr[0].count > m.size/2){
    const len = sortedArr[0].keys.length;
    const index = Math.floor(len * Math.random());
    return sortedArr[0].keys[index];
  } 
  //else return -1
  return -1;
}

console.log(getHighestOccuringKey(m));

m.set('7', 'a');
console.log(getHighestOccuringKey(m));
```

Answer (score 0):

With the existing Map `m`, I would create another Map that has the following structure (for example 1):

```
{
  null: { key: '0', count: 2 },
  a: { key: '1', count: 4 },
  b: { key: '4', count: 1 },
}
```

And then I can find the key which has the highest value. The answer won't be random it would be the first one.

```js
var m = new Map();
m.set('0', null);
m.set('1', 'a');
m.set('2', 'a');
m.set('3', 'a');
m.set('4', 'b');
m.set('5', 'a');
m.set('6', null);

const freq = new Map();
for (let item of m) {
  const [key, val] = item;
  if (freq.has(val)) {
    const temp = freq.get(val);
    freq.set(val, {...temp, count: temp.count + 1})
  }else {
    freq.set(val, {key: key, count: 1})
  }
}

let maxVal = 0;
let maxKey;
for (let item of freq) {
  const [key, val] = item;
  if (val.count > maxVal) {
    maxVal = val.count;
    maxKey = val.key;
  }
}

if (maxVal > m.size * 0.5) {
  console.log(maxKey)
}else {
  console.log(-1)
}
```